# Problema notación big-omega

Tags: algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

No entiendo muy bien como hacer este ejercicio, si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería.

I do not understand very well how to do this exercise, if someone can help me I would appreciate it.

[image: El problema]

[image: Esta es la definicion de big omega que tengo, pero no se como aplicarla este caso.]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: La pregunta es como resolver el ejercicio(7), es decir demostrar que este sumatorio es notación asintomática big omega

Comment: Te recomiendo publicar tu pregunta en [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Esa web está orientada a problemas de matemáticas. StackOverflow está orientado a problemas de programación.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias, lo comentaba por aquí porque lo hemos estudiado en EDA (estructura de datos y algoritmos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La notación big Omega, aunque tiene su formalización matemática, es más fácil de entender "intuitivamente".

Cuando escribes que "algo" es Omega(funcion), quieres decir que ese "algo" crece más rápidamente que esa "funcion", al menos a partir de un cierto valor.

En el caso de tu ejercicio, entiendo que el "algo" sería el tiempo de ejecución del sumatorio (o el número de instrucciones necesarias para computarlo).

Calcular ese sumatorio requeriría un bucle de este estilo  (lo pongo en C, pero en otros lenguajes sería similar):

```
total = 0
for (i=1; i<=N; i++) {
   total = total + i;
}
```

En este caso el número de operaciones ejecutadas dependerá de cuántos elementos sumar, es decir del valor de N. Y se trata de ver que ese número es Omega(N). Ciertamente un mero bucle que se repitiera N veces ya requeriría como mínimo N operaciones aunque no hiciera nada dentro. En este caso además está computando sumas y asignaciones, por lo que el número de operaciones será mayor que N, por lo que "intuitivamente" podemos asegurar que ese número de operaciones es un Omega(N).